# "Unable to update dependencies of the project" after committing to Subversion

Tags: winforms, deployment, dependencies, setup-project

I have a setup project in .NET. When I save the project and the other projects to subversion, the setup project no longer compiles. I get the error "Unable to update dependencies of the project."

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is a long [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/83e136a2-a93f-4abb-8bf9-ba6eafba5a2c) thread about this on MSDN. It seems like there are many possible causes. The discussion includes a few links for this problem from Microsoft. [Here is a hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917036/) for VS2005 and [here is a workaround](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552799) for VS2010.

Comment: The "remove and then add the project again" approach works for me.

Comment: +1 I had to fix the dependency path manually in the .VDPROJ file. See my answer to possibly win some time. The hotfix didn't help at all.

Comment: +1 to radbyx. Your simple comment probably saved me an hour of frustration :)

Comment: Restarting also fixed it for me. Thanks radbyx!

Comment: Closing the solution, then re-opening it. This worked for me :-)

Comment: In Visual studio 2010 I had the same issue , just Removing  the Setup project and add it back again solve the issue

Answer (score 94):

Closing VS2010 and then re-opening it has always worked for me :)

Comment: The fact that I googled this problem, came here and saw that I had already upvoted this answer told me that this was probably gonna work for me. And it did.

Comment: You sir, are awesome yet once again!

Answer (score 34):

I've had the same issue, but none of the mentioned resolutions seemed to work for me.  Rebuilding the setup project would work, but it is a pain, since we include the project outputs of 30+ projects.

The thing I found to work is a very similar approach to what @Marc did.

1. I noted which dependencies were reported by Visual Studio as errors
2. Edit the .vdproj file in Notepad++
3. Search for the .dll that is giving issues. You will see a "ScatterAssemblies" section. If it is empty, delete the whole dll reference
4. Save file

In all cases I had multiple references to the same dll (not sure how this happened)

**Example of correct reference:**

```
"{9F6F8455-1EF1-4B85-886A-4223BCC8E7F7}:_11EC89A306FFB83A269ACC2BF8D8462B"
{
"AssemblyRegister" = "3:1"
"AssemblyIsInGAC" = "11:FALSE"
"AssemblyAsmDisplayName" = "8:Some.OrOther.Lib, Version=1.601.4042.16978, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
                "ScatterAssemblies"
                {
                                "_11EC89A306FFB83A269ACC2BF8D8462B"
                                {
                                "Name" = "8:Some.OrOther.Lib.dll"
                                "Attributes" = "3:512"
                                }
                }
"SourcePath" = "8:Some.OrOther.Lib.dll"
"TargetName" = "8:"
"Tag" = "8:"
"Folder" = "8:_79891234C744498C83755DDEA682F0BF"
"Condition" = "8:"
"Transitive" = "11:FALSE"
"Vital" = "11:TRUE"
"ReadOnly" = "11:FALSE"
"Hidden" = "11:FALSE"
"System" = "11:FALSE"
"Permanent" = "11:FALSE"
"SharedLegacy" = "11:FALSE"
"PackageAs" = "3:1"
"Register" = "3:1"
"Exclude" = "11:FALSE"
"IsDependency" = "11:TRUE"
"IsolateTo" = "8:"
}
```

**Example of incorrect reference:**

```
"{9F6F8455-1EF1-4B85-886A-4223BCC8E7F7}:_11EC89A306FFB83A269ACC2BF8D8462B"
{
"AssemblyRegister" = "3:1"
"AssemblyIsInGAC" = "11:FALSE"
"AssemblyAsmDisplayName" = "8:Some.OrOther.Lib, Version=1.601.4042.16978, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
                "ScatterAssemblies"
                {
                }
"SourcePath" = "8:Some.OrOther.Lib.dll"
"TargetName" = "8:"
"Tag" = "8:"
"Folder" = "8:_79891234C744498C83755DDEA682F0BF"
"Condition" = "8:"
"Transitive" = "11:FALSE"
"Vital" = "11:TRUE"
"ReadOnly" = "11:FALSE"
"Hidden" = "11:FALSE"
"System" = "11:FALSE"
"Permanent" = "11:FALSE"
"SharedLegacy" = "11:FALSE"
"PackageAs" = "3:1"
"Register" = "3:1"
"Exclude" = "11:FALSE"
"IsDependency" = "11:TRUE"
"IsolateTo" = "8:"
}
```

I also got the same  "Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\MyAssembly.dll')" warning that @Marc got ... but the setup project compiles and runs fine.

Comment: I ended up deleting all the `File` assembly references. Worked perfectly.

Comment: This, so many times. I've been tearing my hair out tring to get these errors resolved, and none of the other fixes suggested have worked.

Comment: This worked for me when deleting the entire File section content did not.

Comment: Well, this was a life saver for me even in VS2019.

Answer (score 10):

Correct link for hot-fix for VS2010 is:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=30681

Works fine after installation

Comment: This worked for me.  Restarting VS and editing the .vdproj did not.

Comment: Microsoft Connect has been retired and the link above takes us to a page that doesn't bother to tell where this hotfix is now located.

Answer (score 6):

I had the similar problem and found a fix in this very long and old discussion on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/83e136a2-a93f-4abb-8bf9-ba6eafba5a2c).
As the user 'Jeff Hunsaker' on Thursday, August 26, 2010 5:51 PM answered (direct link not possible):

> I just encountered this when upgrading Visual Studio 2008 Deployment Projects to VS 2010. Hans' (above) solution worked for me.
>
> 1. Edit the .vdproj file in Notepad.
> 2. Search for "SourcePath" = "8:
> 3. For each assembly/dll, provide the full path
> 4. Save file
>
> Within my .vdproj file, I had several entries simply referencing the assembly:
>   "SourcePath" = "8:MyAssembly.DLL"
>
> Even though Visual Studio [somehow] knew the file location, I received the "Unable to update the dependencies of the project" error until I provided the full path:
>
> "SourcePath" = "8:..\..\..\build\bin\MyCompany.MyAssembly.DLL"
>
> Regards,
>
> Jeff...

I noted which dependencies were reported by Visual Studio and wrote a script to fix them in case this is required.

Note that this now gives me a warning "Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\MyAssembly.dll'). But I can live with that.

Answer (score 4):

This solved the same problem for me:
I added the assemblies that were mentioned in the error message to the GAC. When I recompiled the project the dll's appeared under "Detected Dependencies" in the Solution Explorer and I got the same error. Then I excluded the dll's (right-click and select Exclude) and the project finally compiled ok.

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be caused by orphaned files in the "Deployable" -> "File" section of the .vdproj file. You can verify this by removing all files from the setup project in Visual Studio (make a backup first). If you open the .vdproj file with a text editor and still see entries in the "File" section you have this problem. You can note the keys of these files and remove them from the original .vdproj file and it should work again.

Alternatively compile this quick fix program (tested only with Visual Studio 2010):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.Length == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("FixVDProj <path to .vdproj file>");
                return;
            }

            if (!File.Exists(args[0])) {
                throw new Exception("File " + args[0] + " does not exist!");
            }

            string[] strarSource = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);
            List<string> listDest = new List<string>();
            List<string> listKnownKeys = new List<string>();

            int iSection = 0;
            bool bAccept = true;
            bool bNeedFix = false;

            foreach (string strLine in strarSource) {
                switch (iSection) {
                    case 0:
                        if (strLine.Trim() == "\"DeployProject\"") {
                            listDest.Add(strLine);
                            iSection++;
                        } else {
                            throw new Exception("\"DeployProject\" not found");
                        }
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        if (strLine.Trim() == "\"Hierarchy\"") {
                            iSection++;
                        }
                        listDest.Add(strLine);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (strLine.Trim().StartsWith("\"MsmKey\" = ")) {
                            int p = strLine.IndexOf('=');
                            string strMsm = strLine.Substring(p + 1).Trim();
                            if (strMsm.StartsWith("\"8:") && strMsm.EndsWith("\"")) {
                                listKnownKeys.Add(strMsm.Substring(3, strMsm.Length - 4));
                            } else {
                                throw new Exception("Invalid MsmKey " + strMsm);
                            }
                        } else if (strLine.Trim() == "\"Deployable\"") {
                            iSection++;
                        }
                        listDest.Add(strLine);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        if (strLine.Trim() == "\"File\"") {
                            iSection++;
                        }
                        listDest.Add(strLine);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        if (strLine.Trim() == "{") {
                            iSection++;
                        }
                        listDest.Add(strLine);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        if (strLine.Trim() == "}") {
                            listDest.Add(strLine);
                            iSection = -1;  // finished
                        } else if (strLine.Trim().StartsWith("\"") && strLine.Contains(':')) {
                            int p = strLine.IndexOf(':');
                            string strKey = strLine.Substring(p + 1, strLine.Length - p - 2);
                            if (listKnownKeys.Contains(strKey)) {
                                Console.WriteLine("Accepted key " + strKey);
                                bAccept = true;
                                listDest.Add(strLine);
                            } else {
                                Console.WriteLine("Invalid key " + strKey + " removed");
                                bAccept = false;
                                bNeedFix = true;
                            }
                        } else if (strLine.Trim() == "{") {
                            if (bAccept) {
                                listDest.Add(strLine);
                            }
                            iSection++;
                        } else {
                            listDest.Add(strLine);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                    case 8:
                    case 9:
                        if (strLine.Trim() == "{") {
                            iSection++;
                        } else if (strLine.Trim() == "}") {
                            iSection--;
                        }
                        if (bAccept) {
                            listDest.Add(strLine);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 10:
                        throw new Exception("File structure depth exceeded!");

                    default:
                        listDest.Add(strLine);
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (bNeedFix) {
                File.Copy(args[0], args[0] + ".bak", true);
                File.WriteAllLines(args[0], listDest);
                Console.WriteLine("File " + args[0] + " has been fixed!");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("File " + args[0] + " did not need fix!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to work around this issue by removing the installer project from the solution then adding the existing project back in again.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting VS2010 didn't work for me but I managed to get everything working by doing a 'Clean Solution', then a 'Build Solution'. Trying 'Rebuild Solution' after the clean didn't work however. Then I could run the Solution with F5 as normal.

Answer (score 1):

When I get this error I find my VS2010 deployment project (.vdproj) is 'corrupted'.  Specifically, items in the **FILE** section of the VDPROJ file have GUID's that are missing from the **HIERARCHY** section of the VDPROJ file.  This is described in detail below.

1) VS2010 deployment projects include the following sections:

```
"Hierarchy"
{
}
"Deployable"
{
    "File"
    {
    }
}
```

2) The **HIERARCHY** section contains GUIDs for each item (e.g. file) added to the deployment project.  In addition, each file added to the project appears as an item under the **DEPLOYABLE > FILE** section. The following example shows a normal configuration for the file **msimg32.dll**.   Note the matching GUID (i.e. _1C15DB39774F7E79C84F1CC87ECFD60A) in the **HIERARCHY** and **FILE** sections.

```
"Hierarchy"
{
  "Entry"
    {
    "MsmKey" = "8:_1C15DB39774F7E79C84F1CC87ECFD60A"
    "OwnerKey" = "8:_0C67A6B6004040DC93A0113E1100615D"
    "MsmSig" = "8:_UNDEFINED"
    }
  }
"Deployable"
{
  "File"
  {
    "{1FB2D0AE-D3B9-43D4-B9DD-F88EC61E35DE}:_1C15DB39774F7E79C84F1CC87ECFD60A"
    {
        "SourcePath" = "8:MSIMG32.dll"
        "TargetName" = "8:MSIMG32.dll"
        … more information ...
    }
  }
}
```

3) My VS2010 deployment projects can be corrupted in two ways:

- a) An item in the **FILE** section is duplicated and the duplicated item is given a GUID which does not appear in the **HIERARCHY** section.
- b) The GUID associated with an item in the **FILE** section has been removed from the **HIERARCHY** section (i.e. the item in the **FILE** section is orphaned).

3a) Example of first problem - duplicated item in **FILE** section:

In this example, the file **msimg32.dll** has two entries in the **FILE** section.  The first (i.e. correct) entry has a matching GUID (i.e. _1C15DB39774F7E79C84F1CC87ECFD60A) in the **HIERARCHY** section, but the GUID for the second (i.e. error) entry (i.e. 2DDC4FA12BFD46DEAED0053D23331348) does not appear in the **HIERARCHY** section.

```
"Hierarchy"
{
    "Entry"
    {
    "MsmKey" = "8:_1C15DB39774F7E79C84F1CC87ECFD60A"
    "OwnerKey" = "8:_0C67A6B6004040DC93A0113E1100615D"
    "MsmSig" = "8:_UNDEFINED"
    }
}
"Deployable"
{
  "File"
  {
    "{1FB2D0AE-D3B9-43D4-B9DD-F88EC61E35DE}:_1C15DB39774F7E79C84F1CC87ECFD60A"
    {
        "SourcePath" = "8:MSIMG32.dll"
        "TargetName" = "8:MSIMG32.dll"
        … more information ...
    }
    "{1FB2D0AE-D3B9-43D4-B9DD-F88EC61E35DE}:_2DDC4FA12BFD46DEAED0053D23331348"
    {
        "SourcePath" = "8:MSIMG32.dll"
        "TargetName" = "8:MSIMG32.dll"
        … more information ...
    }
  }
}
```

3b) Example of second problem - orphaned item in the **FILE** section:

In this example, the file **msimg32.dll** has an entry in the **FILE** section.  But the GUID associated with this entry (i.e. A515046ADA6244F2A260E67625E4398F) does not have a matching entry in (i.e. it is missing from) the **HIERARCHY** section.

```
"Hierarchy"
{
}
"Deployable"
{
  "File"
  {
    "{1FB2D0AE-D3B9-43D4-B9DD-F88EC61E35DE}:_A515046ADA6244F2A260E67625E4398F"
    {
        "SourcePath" = "8:MSIMG32.dll"
        "TargetName" = "8:MSIMG32.dll"
        … more information ...
    }
  }
}
```

4) Solution: For both problems illustrated above, the solution is to delete the orphaned item in the **FILE** section.

The following example shows how the **FILE** section in point 3a above would appear after the second entry for **msimg32.dll** has been deleted.

```
"Hierarchy"
{
    "Entry"
    {
    "MsmKey" = "8:_1C15DB39774F7E79C84F1CC87ECFD60A"
    "OwnerKey" = "8:_0C67A6B6004040DC93A0113E1100615D"
    "MsmSig" = "8:_UNDEFINED"
    }
}
"Deployable"
{
  "File"
  {
    "{1FB2D0AE-D3B9-43D4-B9DD-F88EC61E35DE}:_1C15DB39774F7E79C84F1CC87ECFD60A"
    {
        "SourcePath" = "8:MSIMG32.dll"
        "TargetName" = "8:MSIMG32.dll"
        … more information ...
    }
  }
}
```

5) I found the corrupted entries in the VDPROJ only occurred for:

- a) assembly files (i.e. DLL) from my C# projects and
- b) detected dependencies from my C++ projects (e.g. version.dll, urlmon.dll)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of solutions that work:

1) Removing one of the problem DLLs from the setup project, and then re-adding just that one resolved the problem for me. This worked even when there were many DLLs with the problem. Removing and adding just one of them triggered VS2010 to fix them all up somehow.

2) Rebuild the solution, then try updating the dependencies again. The rebuild helps visual studio discover what the dependencies are, because it may be struggling to find the dependencies with nothing built.

3) Restart Visual Studio

*The VS2010 hotfix linked above didn't work for me. Sometimes restarting VS2010 will fix the problem and when that doesn't work, doing the above works.*

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you are trying to debug and have selected the Release mode. Got me just now :(

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, that I get the same error when I edit the deployment project from my computer instead of the dedicated compiler computer.

The last time I got that error I needed to roll back the last changes, and re-do it from the dedicated compiler computer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your project references and make sure your project is still looking in the right place for the assembly that the Setup project can't find.

I fixed the issue by going into my `.csproj` file and adding the reference to the dll my Setup project couldn't find.

In my case, my `.csproj` file explicitly points to where my references reside for each built target (Debug|Release|x64|x86).