# Visual Studio 2019 Installer Project WARNING: Unable to update the dependencies of the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, obfuscation

I 'm trying to build a Setup/install project in Visual Studio and my main project uses an obfusiciated third party dll that when compiling the setup project it gets this warning:

> WARNING: Unable to update the dependencies of the project.  The
> dependencies for the object: 'xxxx.dll' cannot be determined.

But no exe or msi is generated.

How does one resolve this warning/error?

Comment: Have you talked to the folks who created your obfuscated DLL?  They should know how to consume it

Comment: Maybe you can try to remove and then add the project again. And here is a relevant thread may help you. [Unable to update the dependencies of the project](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83e136a2-a93f-4abb-8bf9-ba6eafba5a2c/unable-to-update-the-dependencies-of-the-project?forum=csharpide)

Comment: One answer to this question had someone stating they had to modify the project file for the obfusiciated dll [VS 2017 Installer Project Error](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/30ec530b-561d-4092-8f9a-ab6b480e01fa/vs-2017-installer-project-error?forum=winformssetup)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2017 - ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project (setup & deployment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358017/visual-studio-2017-error-unable-to-update-the-dependencies-of-the-project-se)

Answer (score 0):

The project file becomes out of whack and this issue has been endemic to Visual Studio since VS2005.

The best advice I found was to close visual studio and edit the project file. Once there empty the sections of "Hierarchy" and "File" where they look like this:

```
"Hierarchy"
{
}
...
"File" 
{
}
```

Once done reload the project and re-add outputs.